# How to remove the text within the specified starting and ending lines in java

Tags: java, string, text, replace

I am writing scripts to a text file with comments using java. Inside the comment, my sql script is written. I am writing my scripts within the comment **`actions starts`** and **`actions ends`** and I want the script within this comment to be replaced by some other scripts later. **How can I remove the script** which is available inside the specified comment and **add new script**.

```
--
-- `actions` starts
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique actions ID.',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The object  acts on ',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores action.';
--
-- `actions` ends
--

--
-- `operations` starts
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `operations` (
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The object that that action acts on ',
  `callback` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The callback ',
  `parameters` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parameters to be passed to .',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores operations.';
--
-- `operations` ends
--
```

Comment: You have the full script in a `String` or in a file?

Comment: What is the intention? If you describe just a little more about what you are trying to achieve, maybe someone can help find you a short cut.

Comment: I am writing all these scripts in a file.

Comment: Do you want to do this replacing as you're generating the file (using Java, from another file, or from some other source) or as you're running it (in MySQL)? Since this is tagged `java` am I correct in assuming it's the former? (The next question would be - how are you generating it, preferable include some code) Side note - According to my understanding, the lingo is that a script is a bunch of SQL statements (or code) (as in the file is an SQL script) and you want to replace some statements between two comments with some other statements. Using `script` everywhere is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Solutions is to use **indexOf** method to identify the starting and ending blocks. The code that i used is,

```
private static final String VARIABLE_FIELD = "variable";
private static final String END_MODULE_END_TAG = "' ends";
private static final String START_MODULE_END_TAG = "' starts";
private static final String MODULE_START_TAG = "-- '";
private static final String DOUBLE_HYPHEN = "--";
private static final String VALUE_FIELD = "value";
private static final String NAME_FIELD = "name";
private static final String SQL_VARIABLE_SEP = "`,`";
private static final String SQL_VALUE_SEP = "','";
private static final String SINGLE_QUOTE = "'";
private static final String LINE_BREAK = "\n";
private static final String EQUAL = "=";

File scriptFile = new File(versionFile + File.separator + fileName);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
if (scriptFile.isFile()) {
    // if script file is available need to replace the content
    buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(scriptFile));
    String readBuff = buff.readLine();
    String sectionStarts = MODULE_START_TAG + moduleName + START_MODULE_END_TAG;
    String sectionEnds = MODULE_START_TAG + moduleName + END_MODULE_END_TAG;

    while (readBuff != null) {
        sb.append(readBuff);
        sb.append(LINE_BREAK);
        readBuff = buff.readLine();
    }

    int cnt1 = sb.indexOf(sectionStarts);
    int cnt2 = sb.indexOf(sectionEnds);
    if (cnt1 != -1 || cnt2 != -1) {
        sb.replace(cnt1 + sectionStarts.length(), cnt2, LINE_BREAK + queryString + LINE_BREAK);
    } else {
        // if this module is not added already in the file and need to add this config alone
        sb.append(LINE_BREAK + DOUBLE_HYPHEN + LINE_BREAK);
        sb.append(MODULE_START_TAG + moduleName + START_MODULE_END_TAG + LINE_BREAK);
        sb.append(queryString);
        sb.append(LINE_BREAK);
        sb.append(MODULE_START_TAG + moduleName + END_MODULE_END_TAG + LINE_BREAK);
        sb.append(DOUBLE_HYPHEN + LINE_BREAK);
    }
}
```

The key code is

**int cnt1 = sb.indexOf(sectionStarts);
        int cnt2 = sb.indexOf(sectionEnds);
        if (cnt1 != -1 || cnt2 != -1) {
            sb.replace(cnt1 + sectionStarts.length(), cnt2, LINE_BREAK + queryString + LINE_BREAK);
        }**

**int cnt1 = sb.indexOf(sectionStarts);** it identifies the starting tag and **int cnt2 = sb.indexOf(sectionEnds);** identifies the ending tag.

It will find the block and will replace the content with new one.

Comment: I think you could load the file into a String obj (if the file is not huge), and do your processing with regex. you may need multi-line mode. I guess this way will handle it much easier.